# Overhead of casting double to float?

Tags: c++, c

So I have megabytes of data stored as doubles that need to be sent over a network... now I don't need the precision that a double offers, so I want to convert these to a float before sending them over the network.  What is the overhead of simply doing:

```
float myFloat = (float)myDouble;
```

I'll be doing this operation several million times every few seconds and don't want to slow anything down. Thanks

**EDIT:** My platform is x64 with Visual Studio 2008.

**EDIT 2:** I have no control over how they are stored.

Comment: This is going to depend on your compiler and processor. The actual overhead will show up in your assembly - look at the ASM view in visual studio's debugger. (or the -s option for gcc)

Comment: Measure it and see.

Comment: With all due respect this is why I asked it on SO... I didn't want to test it and see hahaha.

Comment: If you don't need the precision, why don't you store them as floats instead?

Comment: I have no control over how they are stored else I would :(

Comment: Are you trying to speed up your network traffic?  Are you sure changing from float to double would do that?

Comment: well it would cut down the size of the data I'm sending.

Comment: Again, I suggest that you look at the assembly.

Comment: Okay, so look up in the manual the cycles of each of those instructions in the asm, feed that into your CPU's hertz and that will be your worst case overhead cost. A modern cpu will do better than that due to interleaved instructions and pipelines & so forth, but now you have an upper bound.

Comment: If they're IEEE 754 doubles and floats, converting between them is a question of a few bit shifts. The time spent by even million conversions is negligible. Compared to network speeds, it's practically zero.

Comment: "You have to measure it" seems to have become the chicken out reply: no need to think about the question anymore.

Comment: Why is that chickening out? Manually examining the assembly and counting CPU cycles is complicated (because you need to learn how to do something), slow (because you're doing it manually), and inaccurate (you get it wrong because you don't take into account pipelines, interleaving, etc, all the clever stuff the processor does that you're not clever enough for). Measuring is simple, fast, and accurate. Am I cheating if I pick the right tool to save time?

Comment: Also, measuring it will give you an answer for one compiler, with one set of compiler options, on one operating system, on one processor. Possibly also affected by other factors. Obviously the answer to a question like this is very much dependent on the compiler and platform, but I find an answer like "it takes a few bit shifts" much more useful than "measure it" because I can correlate bit shifts to other systems wheras the measure it results are meaningless everywhere but where it was tested. Measuring is great to test one thing relative to another ON THE SAME SYSTEM, but bad for absolutes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Michael Burr said, while the overhead strongly depends on your platform, the overhead is definitely less than the time needed to send them over the wire.

---

a rough estimate:

800MBit/s payload on a excellent Gigabit wire, 25M-floats/second.

On a 2GHz single core, that gives you a whopping **80** clock cycles for each value converted to break even - anythign less, and you will save time. That should be more than enough on all architectures :)

A simple load-store cycle (barring all caching delays) should be below 5 cycles per value. With instruction interleaving, SIMD extensions and/or parallelizing on multiple cores, you are likely to do multiple conversions in a single cycle.

Also, the receiver will be happy having to handle only half the data. Remember that memory access time is nonlinear.

---

The only thing arguing against the conversion would be is if the transfer should have minimal CPU load: a modern architecture could transfer the data from disk/memory to bus without CPU intervention. However, with above numbers I'd say that doesn't matter in practice.

**[edit]**
I checked some numbers, the 387 coprocessor would indeed have taken around 70 cycles for a load-store cycle. On the initial pentium, you are down to 3 cycles without any parallelization.

So, unless you run a gigabit network on a 386...

Comment: Thanks for explaining it on the low level... this is good stuff.  When dealing with lots of data, every clock cycle matters!

Answer (score 7):

It's going to depend on your implementation of C++ libraries. Test it and see.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I would say it is the only answer to all "What is the overhead of xxx" questions

Answer (score 5):

Even if it does take time this will not be the slow point in your application.
Your FPU can do the conversion a lot quicker than it can send network traffic (so the bottleneck here will more than likely be the write to the socket).

But as with al things like this measure it and see.

Personally I **don't** think any time spent here will affect the real time spent sending the data.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're talking about a significant number of packets to ship the data (a reasonable assumption if you're sending millions of values) casting the doubles to float will likely reduce the number of network packets by about half (assuming `sizeof(double)==8` and `sizeof(float)==4`).

Almost certainly the savings in network traffic will dominate whatever time is spent performing the conversion.  But as everyone says, measuring some tests will be the proof of the pudding.

Comment: yes!  this is exactly why I was interested in doing the conversion... some other posters didn't realize this :)

Answer (score 3):

Bearing in mind that most compilers deal with `doubles` a lot more efficiently than `floats` -- many promote `float` to `double` before performing operations on them -- I'd consider taking the block of data, ZIPping/compressing it, then sending the compressed block across. Depending on what your data looks like, you could get 60-90% compression, vs. the 50% you'd get converting 8-byte values to four bytes.

Comment: compression would be for sure slower than casting double to float, even if the numeric performance of the arithmetic operations is _the same_ (not better, as both will be probably promoted to extended format internally).

Comment: Hmmm very interesting... I'm not sure if it will have to be compressed (most likely not) but this could be a better solution then converting them.  Any compression algorithms off the top of your head?  Thanks

Comment: @fortran - absolutely, however how much slower vs. transmission time is still an unkinown without direct observation.

Comment: @Polaris878 - consider LZW compression. I'm pretty sure it's copywritten, but you should be able to find a usable implementation. Or at least it will point you to a solution!

Comment: What CPUs promote `float` to `double`? Are you by chance confusing it with x86/x64, which promotes both `float` and `double` to `long double` when loading into FPU registers, with default settings?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that 60-90% is reasonable? The figures I pull out of my rear are much lower than that. All but one or two bytes of each value are likely to be nearly random.

Comment: As peterchen's answer points out, a rough estimate suggests that the time required to transmist the results across the network dominates that of any reasonably simple calculation, so better compression may offer a more significant speedup.

Answer (score 3):

I think this cast is a lot cheaper than you think since it doesn't really involve any kind of calculation. In fact, it's just bitshifting to get rid of some of the digits of exponent and mantissa.

Comment: The straightforward implementation is a FLD/FSTP pair (i.e. load the double on the floating point stack, write it back as float), so the conversion is likely implemented in hardware. It would be a bit mroe expensive in software - you need correct rounding and need to check range overflow.

Comment: After checking the assembly code, these are the exact instructions it is doing.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any choice but to measure them yourself and see. You could use timers to measure them. Looks like some has already implemented a neat [C++ timer class](http://sites.google.com/site/jivsoft/Home/timer)

Answer (score 1):

It will also depend on the CPU and what floating point support it has.  In the bad old days (1980s), processors supported integer operations only.  Floating point math had to be emulated in software.  A separate chip for floating point (a [coprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprocessor)) could be bought separately.

Modern CPUs now have [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions, so large amounts of floating point data can be processed at once.  These instructions include MMX, SSE, 3DNow! and the like.  Your compiler may know how to make use of these instructions, but you may need to write your code in a particular way, and turn on the right options.

Finally, the fastest way to process floating point data is in a video card.  A fairly new language called [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) lets you send tasks to the video card to be processed there.

It all depends on how much performance you need.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly why... all this data will be going to the video card on the other side of the network... so i want to make the data nice and neat before it reaches the client to be rendered.

Comment: OpenCL doesn't guarantee support for doubles and since he's not doing any real computation OpenCL might not be a good choice.