# Division of double with a float

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, division

I have a doubt about precision and speed in division between double and float.

e.g:

```
double a;
a=myfun(); //returns a number with lots of decimals
float b=5.0;
double result=a/b;
```

Would the result change if b would be double?
Does it take more time to compute if they are not doubles (because of changing the size of the float for fitting the double size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the result change if b would be double?

Since the value is 0.5, the result should not change. If it was a different value, it might change, because double has better precision then float.

> Does it take more time to compute if they are not doubles?

Yes, it does. But the time to convert from float to double can be really neglected.

Comment: On x86 FPU there is no penalty, since both, 32-bit float and 64-bit double are converted to 80-bit extended precision when loaded to the registers.

Comment: @ybungalobill Converting one to another is really a micro-optimization, but there are some penalties. See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1467057/476681). If nothing, then 64-bit double needs more clock cycles to transfer. Anyway, the overhead can be neglected.

Answer (score 2):

The time difference between conversion from float to double or double to float is really negligible

Check out this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) it will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this? b is converted to `double` during division anyway. Floating point divisions are expensive, and time taken for divisions of float is slightly faster.